# ASPxDateEdit Change Header

Tags: datetime, devexpress, datetime-format

Is there any way to modify the format of the calendar header of `DateEdit` control? Before upgrading to v.10.2.8.0 (I was using 10.1.6.0) the format of the calendar header was `MMMM, YYYY` (e.g. July, 2011). After upgrading, the format changed to `YYYY MMMM` (e.g. 2011 July).

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code used to format the calendar's Title text:

```
        TitleLabel.Text = ViewInfo.VisibleDate.ToString(IsRightToLeft ? "MMMM yyyy" : CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.YearMonthPattern);
```

So, the only solution is to change the CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.YearMonthPattern setting.  This can be done within the page's [InitializeCulture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.initializeculture.aspx) method.

Comment: I think I cannot use this in DevEx. :|

Comment: The fact is that this code hasn't been changed and you should check what is the value of the  CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.YearMonthPattern parameter.

Comment: I think I'm getting it, will look into this. Thanks